# Como hacer un Trigger para descontar stock de los ingredientes a partir de un producto que ordenan.?

Tags: mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Quiero me orienten como puedo hacer un Trigger que me permita actualizar el stock de los ingredientes que componen un producto, partiendo de la receta que lo contiene.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tr_updStockIngredients AFTER INSERT ON detail_orders
 FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
    DECLARE ingredient_id INT;
    DECLARE quantity DECIMAL;

    SELECT recp.ingredient_id, recp.quantity INTO ingredient_id, quantity
    FROM detail_orders deor, recipes recp 
    WHERE deor.food_id=NEW.food_id //5
    AND recp.food_id = deor.food_id;

    UPDATE ingredients SET stock_per_measure = stock_per_measure - quantity
    WHERE ingredients.id = ingredient_id;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

el error generado:

"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1172 Result consisted of more than one row (SQL: insert into detail_orders (order_id, comment, food_id, quantity, price, updated_at, created_at) values (47, ?, 1, 1, 5000.00, 2020-04-09 22:00:12, 2020-04-09 22:00:12))"

Comment: Al tratar de hacer un `SELECT` dentro del **trigger** no tiene mucha utilidad a menos que lo agregues a una sentencia `SET` y además no pasa tu consulta a través de la tabla foods.

Comment: @synay, gracias por la observación. igualmente ya lo pude solucionar.